# How to overwrite label in tkinter, after running another functions

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making GUI the first time with tkinter(python), and I want to show the results in the same place, where they are at the beginning.

When I run this code the functions are fully working, but I cannot show the results in my label.

The button have to take data from Entries and give it to the function with data from drop-down list.

The results should overwrite the list as1, as2 = [0, 0] and then show the results on the label result_1, result_2

I've tried to add "master" parameter to the function - onclick, but then the GUI was running without clicking the button.

```py
# coding=utf-8
from tkinter import *


def function_1(h, eta_bet):
    print(h, eta_bet)
    return h, eta_bet


def calculated_value_concrete(class_concrete):  # could be 20/25
    eta_bet = class_concrete
    return eta_bet


class Menu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        container = Label(master, bg="#003366")
        container.pack()

        menu_bg = Label(container, bg="#003366", fg="white", pady=15)
        countings_bg = Label(container)

        self.button1 = Button(menu_bg, text="Zbrojenie symetryczne", command=lambda: self.onclick(1, countings_bg),
                              width=20)

        menu_bg.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

        self.button1.pack()

    def onclick(self, args, countings_bg):
        if args == 1:
            countings_bg.pack()
            ZbrojenieSymetryczne(countings_bg)


class ZbrojenieSymetryczne:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.desc_1 = Label(master, text="Wysokość przekroju h [cm]")
        self.desc_7 = Label(master, text="Wybór betonu")
        self.data_1 = Entry(master, width=6)

        var = StringVar()
        var.set("Klasa")

        self.data_7 = OptionMenu(master, var, "1", "2", command=self.option_menu)
        self.data_7.config(width=10)

        self.desc_1.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        self.desc_7.grid(row=7, sticky=E)

        self.data_1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.data_7.grid(row=7, column=1, stick="ew")

        self.button5 = Button(master, text="Count", command=self.onclick)
        self.button5.grid(row=9, columnspan=2, pady=10)

        as1, as2 = [0, 0]

        self.result_1 = Label(master, text=f"A_s1 = {as1} [cm^2]")
        self.result_1.grid(row=12, sticky=E)
        self.result_2 = Label(master, text=f"A_s2 = {as2} [cm^2]")
        self.result_2.grid(row=13, sticky=E)

    def option_menu(self, selection):
        self.eta_bet = calculated_value_concrete(selection)
        print(self.eta_bet)

    def onclick(self):
        h = float(self.data_1.get().replace(',', '.')) * 10 ** -2

        as1, as2 = function_1(h, self.eta_bet)

        self.result_1 = Label(master, text=f"A_s1 = {as1} [cm^2]")
        self.result_1.grid(row=12, sticky=E)
        self.result_2 = Label(master, text=f"A_s2 = {as2} [cm^2]")
        self.result_2.grid(row=13, sticky=E)


root = Tk()
root.title("Obliczanie zbrojenia")

Menu(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I want the results in the same label as it is in the beginning (under the button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the text of an existing label there are many ways to do this but perhaps consider doing this inside your `onclick` function rather than creating new buttons.

```
def onclick(self):
    h = float(self.data_1.get().replace(',', '.')) * 10 ** -2

    as1, as2 = function_1(h, self.eta_bet)

    self.result_1['text'] = f"A_s1 = {as1} [cm^2]"
    self.result_2['text'] = f"A_s2 = {as2} [cm^2]"
```

This should set the text of result_1 and result_2 as per the f-string.

Comment: Thank you it is working, but there is another problem. When I click "count" button, then every other thing is disappearing instantly and I'm staying just with results without data and description on this data.
Also I'm curious whether option menu is written properly, because pycharm print out warning that "instant attribute eta_bet defined outside __init__"

Comment: I can't see anything in the code you've posted so far that would cause everything to disappear. I'd probably ignore the pycharm warning. If you have another problem, raise a new question